# web crawler: fetch only useful html content to speed up fetching in php

Tags: php, web, web-crawler

I am designing a web crawler to fetch a list of products from a site. I have tried **simple HTML DOM parser** and **file_get_contents()** to fetch HTML and parse it. But it is taking too much time to fetch the HTML content. Also a lots of parsing overhead as it is a huge size page. I am looking for a way if possible to fetch only required HTML content to speed up fetching. like.. using offset and maxlen parameters in file_get_contents(). but Seeking (offset) is not supported with remote files.

```
 string file_get_contents ( string $filename,false, 9000, 5000)
```

Does there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do this at the HTTP protocol level using the `Range` headers in the request. But, it is not guaranteed that the other server understands or honors them. Further, do you *really* know the exact byte offset of the content that interests you? Sounds like that would be really brittle. Also, if you're only fetching a partial HTML document, you may have a hard time parsing it.

Look at the `$context` parameter of `file_get_contents` and related documentation about Contexts for setting HTTP headers and try the `Range` header.